# How to get popup message after log into Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

We are using linux Servers (CentOS) and one backup server
We only login to prod server if any there is any issue, else we check connection from backup server

We do no have any kind of monitoring tool

I have created a simple bash script on backup server as below

```
 #!/bin/bash
 date
 cat /tmp/servers.txt | while read output
 do
    ping -c 1 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Server $output is UP"
    else
    echo "Server $output is Down"
    fi
done
```

How do we get output of this script after log into this server automatically.

Comment: You would have to redirect output to `/etc/motd`.

Comment: @MarkoE, thought of that, However we are not allowed to change MOTD.

Comment: You have several common antipatterns in this short script. Try http://shellcheck.net/ for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` runs every time you log in, so that seems like the place you would want to put this code.